# Matrices - Which of the two expressions would you choose to use in software that implements matrix multiplication and transposition?

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

You know that the following two expressions are equivalent:

$B^T$, $A^T$ and $(AB)^T$. Which of the two expressions would you choose to use in software that implements matrix multiplication and transposition? In the context of implementing the most efficient operation (i.e. such that your code is faster and uses less (disk or memory) storage).

In my opinion I believe it's $(AB)^T$, I am not really sure why but maybe because it takes less computations... anyone else got a better opinion?

Comment: Is your question $(AB)^T$ less time consuming than $B^TA^T$ ? It depends on so many things in particular the way the storage is organized ...  (for example, $A^T$ is not necessarily associated with moving elements...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may depend to some extent on details of how things are organized, details that we might not be accessible to us.

Presumably the actual matrix multiplications take the same time in both cases, and the only difference is that $B^T A^T$ requires two transposition operations while $(A B)^T$ requires just one.   The question is whether that one transposition of $AB$ could be more costly than the two transpositions of $B$ and $A$.  That might be the case in some circumstances: if $A$ and $B$ are sparse matrices, $AB$ might have many more nonzero elements than $A$ and $B$, and so if the cost of transposition of a sparse matrix is proportional to the 
number of nonzero entries, $B^T A^T$ might actually be better than $(AB)^T$. 
On the other hand $AB$ might turn out to have fewer nonzero elements than $A$ and $B$.

On the third hand, these operations are so fast in modern computers that your matrices would have to be really enormous for the difference in computation time to be greater than the time you spent wondering about which to choose.

Answer (score 0):

I believe computing $(AB)^T$ is faster than $B^T A^T$. While they are equal, the latter requires two index exchanges while the former only requires one.

Assuming both $A$ and $B$ are square, here's what we can do:

```
for i = 1:n
    for j = 1:n
        % The multiplication routine goes here.
        c(i, j) = a(i, :) .* b(:, j);
    end
end

c = c';
```

Everything here uses MATLAB's notation. This can be further optimized if either matrix is sparse, but in general you should compute the product and then transpose.

In fact we can do a bit better:

```
for i = 1:n
    for j = 1:n
        % The multiplication routine goes here.
        c(i, j) = a(j, :) .* b(:, i);
    end
end
```

This avoids the transposition operation at the end by adjusting the multiplication in the loop.

Comment: I disagree: I just tested it on Matlab, and I found on extensive simulations that the computation of $B^T A^T$ is slightly more efficient than $(AB)^T$... ($3.78 \times 10^{-4}$ vs. $4 \times 10^{-4}$ for two $100 \times 100$ random matrix.

Comment: Both these variants are generally bad. The dot product implementation of the matrix-matrix multiplication will never be cache efficient for a given storage scheme.

Comment: True, yeah... I just wanted to give a basic understanding.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.  For example, that computation of $XA^T$ will be much faster than $XA$ if the underlying data is stored in row major form (most implementations).  Accessing the columns of $A^T$ will be faster since it will be the rows of $A$.

Also, transpose can be implemented with just a flag setting and may not involve any operation until the elements are accessed.